# How to detect an array of strings and an array of objects in my data using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a data object like so

```
{0: "aaaaaaajkhkjhjkhd", customer_name: "SAWTELL NEWS aaaa", bar: Array(2), product totals: "DT 42 - 7 Bulk, 12 Odds, 0 Posters, 572 Supply, 0 Key", summary: {…}
```

Which is an object, I would like to loop thru each item and detect the array of strings

```
arrayOfStrings = ['test', 'test]
```

and an array of objects

```
arrayOfObjects = [{}.{}]
```

I need to be able to detect if my data is an array of strings and is so stringify it and if it's an array of objects do Y.

Basically I want to stringify bar: Array(2) and pull out summary: {…} or all the array of objects and not bar: Array(2)

Comment: What do you wanna do if it's mixed?

Comment: Loop over my data, and just pull out the array of strings

Comment: Is `summary` an array? or just an object?

Comment: Summary is an object i.e. - summary
:
{header: "Bulk, Odds, Key", totals: Array(1)}
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: And bar is (2) ["aaaaa", "ddfdfdfdfd"] which is what I'm trying to seperate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.every` to see if every element is `object` or `string`.

```js
let arrStrings = ['a', 'b', []];
let arrObj = [{ a: '1' }, { b: 'test' }, ''];

let isAllStrings = arrStrings.every(i => Object.prototype.toString.call(i) === '[object String]');
let isAllObj = arrObj.every(i => Object.prototype.toString.call(i) === '[object Object]');
```

EDIT :

You can `reduce` the object's keys into a new object.

```js
var data = {
    0: "aaaaaaajkhkjhjkhd", customer_name: "SAWTELL NEWS aaaa", bar: ['aaaa', 'bbbb'], totals: "DT 42 - 7 Bulk, 12 Odds, 0 Posters, 572 Supply, 0 Key", summary: { header: "Bulk, Odds, Key", totals: Array(1) }
};
let obj = Object.keys(data).reduce((acc, i) => {
    if (isArrayOfType(data[i], 'String'))
        return acc[i] = JSON.stringify(data[i]), acc;
    if (isArrayOfType(data[i], 'Object') || isOfType(data[i], 'Object'))
        return acc[i] = data[i], acc;
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(obj)
function isArrayOfType(arr, type) {
    if (!Array.isArray(arr)) return false;
    return arr.every(i => isOfType(i, type));
}
function isOfType(i, type) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(i) === `[object ${type}]`;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but note that the prototype chain always ends in Object, so Object.prototype.toString.call(i) is the same as i.toString()

Comment: If one of the items in the arr is undefined/null, calling toString on it will fail

Comment: @AlmogKoren Answer updated. See if that works for you.

Comment: @JohanP this works but it only returns the keys I need to return the entire object with the key

Comment: @JohanP that's great, thanks. I commented out "return {[i]:JSON.stringify(result[i])}" as I don't need that right now but my question now everything is returned like so  [{…}, {…}] which is an array of objects but I just want to return it all in one object like so {drops: Array(1), summary: {…}}

Comment: @AlmogKoren Ok, I think the last edit will sort you out

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let object of array) {
    let type = typeof object;
    if (type === 'string') {
        doStringLogic;
    }
    else if (type === 'object') {
        doObjectLogic;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using **Object.values**, then loop over it with **forEach** and then detect the required arrays with the methods provided by *JohanP*.
**JSON.stringify** should do the work for the strings array.

Comment: That will not work as it will fail once it hits an object that is not an object of strings result[property1].every is not a function